# change nan values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In my code the df.fillna() method is not working when the df.dropna() method is working. I don't want to drop the column though. What can I do that the fillna() method works?

```
def preprocess_df(df):
    for col in df.columns:  # go through all of the columns
        if col != "target":  # normalize all ... except for the target itself!
            df[col] = df[col].pct_change()  # pct change "normalizes" the different currencies (each crypto coin has vastly diff values, we're really more interested in the other coin's movements)
            # df.dropna(inplace=True)  # remove the nas created by pct_change
            df.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)
            print(df)
            break
            df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)  # scale between 0 and 1.
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your data.

Comment: If you `dropna`, the NAs are gone. Of course `fillna` will have nothing to fill...

Comment: Your `df.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)` does not need to be within your loop since it is acting on `df` as a whole rather than just the column.

Comment: @ user9468014 [What you should do when someone answers your ques](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first value was a NaN so I had to use **bfill** method instead. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

it should work unless its not within loop as mentioned..

You should consider filling it before you construct a loop or during the DataFrame construction:

Example Below cleary shows it working :

```
>>> df
  col1
0  one
1  NaN
2  two
3  NaN
```

Works as expected:

```
>>> df['col1'].fillna( method ='ffill')  # This is showing column specific to `col1`

0    one
1    one
2    two
3    two
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Secondly, if you wish to change few selective columns then you use below method:

Let's suppose  you have 3 columns and want to `fillna` with `ffill` for only 2 columns.

```
>>> df
  col1  col2 col3
0  one  test  new
1  NaN   NaN  NaN
2  two  rest  NaN
3  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Define the columns to be changed..

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']

>>> df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(method ='ffill')
>>> df
  col1  col2 col3
0  one  test  new
1  one  test  NaN
2  two  rest  NaN
3  two  rest  NaN
```

If you are considering it to be happen across entire DataFrame, the use it during  as Follows:

```
>>> df
  col1  col2
0  one  test
1  NaN   NaN
2  two  rest
3  NaN   NaN

>>> df.fillna(method ='ffill')  # inplace=True if you considering as you wish for permanent change.
  col1  col2
0  one  test
1  one  test
2  two  rest
3  two  rest
```